# Mock/Stub out filesystem in F# for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, functional-programming, f#, mocks

I'm looking to do some basic verification testing on my functions that write to the filesystem.

I took a hint from [here](https://britebit.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/my-first-experience-of-f-object-expressions/) on how to mock out the filesystem using an interface, but I'm kinda bummed on how the `FileSystemOperations` type needs to be passed along through every function. Any ideas how to improve this, or where I went wrong?

I'm rather new to FP, so any feedback on other design issues are welcome as well.

```
module FileSystem =

    open System.IO

    type IFileSystemOperations = 
        abstract member copy: string -> string -> bool -> unit
        abstract member delete: string -> unit
        abstract member readAllBytes: string -> byte[]
        abstract member createDirectory: string -> DirectoryInfo
        abstract member directoryExists: string -> bool

    type FileSystemOperations () =
        interface IFileSystemOperations with
            member this.copy source destination overwrite =
                File.Copy(source, destination, overwrite)

            member this.delete path =
                File.Delete path

            member this.readAllBytes path =
                File.ReadAllBytes path

            member this.createDirectory path =
                Directory.CreateDirectory path

            member this.directoryExists path =
                let fileInfo = FileInfo path
                fileInfo.Directory.Exists

module FileMover =

    open FileSystem

    let private ensureDirectoryExists (fileSystemsOperations:IFileSystemOperations) destination =
        let directoryExists = fileSystemsOperations.directoryExists destination
        if not (directoryExists) then
            fileSystemsOperations.createDirectory destination |> ignore

    let private compareFiles (fileSystemsOperations:IFileSystemOperations) moveRequest =
        let sourceStream = fileSystemsOperations.readAllBytes moveRequest.Source
        let destinationStream = fileSystemsOperations.readAllBytes moveRequest.Destination
        sourceStream = destinationStream

    let private copyToDestination (fileSystemsOperations:IFileSystemOperations) (moveRequest:MoveRequest) =
        ensureDirectoryExists fileSystemsOperations moveRequest.Destination
        fileSystemsOperations.copy moveRequest.Source moveRequest.Destination true

    let private deleteSource (fileSystemsOperations:IFileSystemOperations) (move:Move) =
        fileSystemsOperations.delete move.Request.Source

    let private moveFile (fileSystemsOperations:IFileSystemOperations) moveRequest =
        copyToDestination fileSystemsOperations moveRequest
        let filesMatch = compareFiles fileSystemsOperations moveRequest
        let move = match filesMatch with
                   | true -> {Request = moveRequest; Result = Success}
                   | false -> {Request = moveRequest; Result = Failure BytesDidNotMatch}

        deleteSource fileSystemsOperations move

    let move (fileSystemsOperations:IFileSystemOperations) targetPath pictures =
        let moveFile = moveFile fileSystemsOperations

        pictures
        |> getMoveRequests targetPath
        |> Seq.map moveFile
```

**Update (for reference & anyone interested)**

Based on the answers below, [here](https://github.com/koenmetsu/Muffin.Pictures.Archiver/blob/92d324b6cccaf21e05fa51557b56e146864080dc/src/Muffin.Pictures.Archiver/FileMover.fs#L41) is how I currently refactored the code. It's a work in progress, but it's already more easily testable (main goal) and the responsibilities seem to fit better as well (eg: injecting `ensureDirectoryExists` into `copyToDestination` instead of into `moveFile`).

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: This article may be superficially relevant: http://blog.jessitron.com/2015/06/ultratestable-coding-style.html

Comment: FWIW, for some time, I haven't been entirely happy with my below answer, so I wrote a series of articles about this problem, culminating in this one: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/09/16/picture-archivist-in-f

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even though the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) are known to be principles related to Object-Oriented Design, I'd still take a cue from the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). As [APPP](http://amzn.to/19W4JHk) states it (ch. 11): **"clients [...] own the abstract interfaces"**.

You can apply this principle in FP as well, in the sense that you can start by defining the overall behaviour of the function you're interested in, and then see what happens.

As an example, I'd approach the `ensureDirectoryExists` function like this:

```
let private ensureDirectoryExists destination =
    let directoryExists = dirExists destination
    if not directoryExists then
        createDir destination
```

Now, **the above version doesn't compile**, because `dirExists` and `createDir` aren't defined. However, that's easy to fix: just promote them to function arguments:

```
let private ensureDirectoryExists dirExists createDir destination =
    let directoryExists = dirExists destination
    if not directoryExists then
        createDir destination
```

Viola: now you have a higher-order function; it's type is

```
('a -> bool) -> ('a -> unit) -> 'a -> unit
```

No interfaces are required.

This is already intriguing for a couple of reasons:

- It's no longer about files or directories: `'a` could be `string` values containing file names or directory names, but it could also be `DirectoryInfo` or something not at all related to files.
- Although it looks complex, it only involves two types: `'a` and `unit`. That should make us pay attention as well.
- You can use partial application to apply the `ensureDirectoryExists` with the two first arguments, and then use this partially applied function to test any number of different directories.

You can still 'implement' `dirExists` and `createDir`, and apply them like this:

```
open System.IO

let directoryExists path =
    let fileInfo = FileInfo path
    fileInfo.Directory.Exists

let ensureDirectoryExists' =
    ensureDirectoryExists directoryExists (Directory.CreateDirectory >> ignore)
```

Notice that the `createDir` 'implementation' is so simple that I chose to inline it. I could also have inlined the `dirExists` 'implementation' with `(fun path -> (FileInfo path).Directory.Exists)`, but I chose to do this as a separate function in order to illustrate the various options available.

The partially applied `ensureDirectoryExists'` function has this simple function signature: `(string -> unit)`, which is comparable to the OP version of the function.

---

While I think I'll leave the rest of the functions as an exercise, I'd like to return to the thought-provoking signature of the `ensureDirectoryExists` function:

```
('a -> bool) -> ('a -> unit) -> 'a -> unit
```

There's nothing here about files or directories, so a more generic name might be in place. It looks like the [Tester-Doer idiom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009.aspx), so we could call it `testDo` instead.

One of the great benefits of making the interface more generic is that **you don't need to involve the file system at all for testing**. Instead, you can test this function using integers, strings, or some other 'easy' values. If the logic is unconstrained generic and works for numbers and strings, it'll also work for directories and files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mark. I like the thinking behind making these more generic, but won't using these separate functions instead of the IFileSystemOperations bloat the public move function with the injection of all five functions in IFileSystemOperations? ie: let move directoryExists createDirectory readBytes delete copy targetPath pictures = //...

Comment: As far as I can tell, `move` depends on one other function: `moveFile` (although I can't tell where `getMoveRequests` comes from, so it may depend on two functions...). It's a simple repetition of the exercise done above. Instead of *ending* with the public function, *start* by defining the public function and see what it needs in order to work.

Comment: Are you suggesting to inject the `moveFile` function into `move`? In that case, it seems there's not much reason for `move` to exist anymore. And if not, then `move` needs to be injected with the functions upon which `moveFile` depends, and it gets bloated. It's probably my currently limited understanding, but could you clarify this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm suggesting injecting *some* `moveFile` function into `move`. Once you've done that, you can look at its inferred type to figure out what you need to do next. Then you can repeat the process in a recursive fashion. It's an outside-in process that I describe (among much else) in my [Type-Driven Development course](http://bit.ly/1T1vLqu).

Comment: I've seen that one, so either I'm still missing something, or I need to take this a bit further than I have been. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Perhaps it'll help with an exercise: try to write the final `move` function first, and then write all the 'dependency functions' *below* that function, so that you start with the most high-level function first, and then functions become more and more specific the lower on the page they are.

Answer (score 6):

I think that Mark's answer gives a great alternative perspective here.

That said, I would probably write something that's quite similar to what you did here. There is a couple of small tricks that I would perhaps use to make the code a bit nicer (at least for my own personal idea of "nicer" F# code :-)), so I thought I'd share those.

First of all, I would probably use `PascalCase` and tuples-syntax for the definition of the interface. The `PascalCase` is recommended for members and I think it makes sense to keep those aligned with the .NET style. You can also omit `member`:

```
type IFileSystemOperations = 
    abstract Copy: string * string * bool -> unit
    abstract Delete: string -> unit
    abstract ReadAllBytes: string -> byte[]
    abstract CreateDirectory: string -> DirectoryInfo
    abstract DirectoryExists: string -> bool
```

Another thing you could do would be to use object expression rather than a full class. Here I don't really have one preferred option. But I might write:

```
let FileSystemOperations =
    { new IFileSystemOperations with
        member this.Copy(source, destination, overwrite) =
            File.Copy(source, destination, overwrite)
        (* ... *) }
```

The next thing that is a bit unfortunate is that you always have to write `fileSystemOperations:IFileSystemOperations`, which makes all your method headers long.

If the private helpers are not used anywhere else, you could avoid this by turning them into local functions. That said, this might not be all that nice, because it makes the `move` function very long (just syntactically, not logically):

```
let move (fileSystemsOperations:IFileSystemOperations) targetPath pictures =
  let ensureDirectoryExists destination =
    let directoryExists = fileSystemsOperations.directoryExists destination
    if not (directoryExists) then
        fileSystemsOperations.createDirectory destination |> ignore

  let compareFiles moveRequest =
    let sourceStream = fileSystemsOperations.readAllBytes moveRequest.Source
    let destinationStream = fileSystemsOperations.readAllBytes moveRequest.Destination
    sourceStream = destinationStream

  let copyToDestination (moveRequest:MoveRequest) =
    ensureDirectoryExists oveRequest.Destination
    fileSystemsOperations.copy moveRequest.Source moveRequest.Destination true

  let deleteSource (move:Move) =
    fileSystemsOperations.delete move.Request.Source

  let moveFile moveRequest =
    copyToDestination moveRequest
    let filesMatch = compareFiles moveRequest
    let move = 
      { Request = moveRequest; 
        Result = if filesMatch then Success else Failure BytesDidNotMatch}

  deleteSource move
  pictures
  |> getMoveRequests targetPath
  |> Seq.map moveFile
```

I also think there is no point in pattern matching over booleans, because you are effectively just writing simple `if` with more complex syntax, so I turned your original pattern match into an inline `if` in `moveFiles`

(I also changed spacing to 2 spaces in the last snippet, but that's just to fit things on the web page).

**EDIT:** Using nested local functions would also quite nicely work with Mark's suggestion to pass around functions. This way, you would not have to propagate them through all the other helper functions, so it might even look nicer than  my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tomas. Your small improvements are very useful, I was actually trying to go for object expressions but clearly dropped the ball there :D Your comment about nested local functions is very interesting, I'm curious to see what I can achieve with the combination!